# Анимация после параметра Apply Root Motion стоит на месте в Unity

Tags: unity3d, анимация

У меня **“in-place”** анимация. Из **unity docs** статьи

> **"Туториал: Скриптинг Root Motion для гуманоидных “in-place” анимаций."**
>
> Это означает, что при размещении персонажа с такой анимацией в сцену,
>   она не будет перемещать персонаж. Другими словами, анимация не
>   содержит “root motion"

советы в docs мне не помогли, нужна Ваша помощь.

Я повесил на обьект (далее - персонаж) компонент **Animator**, добавил **Controller** с  **In Place** анимацией (бега), всё шло хорошо но он игнорировал свой **коллайдер** перед всеми другими и проходил всё, дело в том что этот персонаж **AI**, и он ходил с **Nav Mesh Agent** компонентом и **Character Controller**,

[image: Описание Nav Mesh]

Проблему решал параметр **Apply Root Motion**, после включения анимация (бега) он стал бежать на месте но уже не пропуская через **коллайдер**, вот параметры анимации

[image: Анимация]

Как решить данную проблему? Поставил также на него коллайдер поверх того что дал **Character Controller** это помогло, но зачем мне добавлять коллайдер поверх другого, как по мне это не правильно. Спасибо за внимание

Comment: И для пояснения он ходит по уже запеченным статичным объектам которые требуются для навигации

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Решил проблему!**

Дело в том что когда то я создавал анимации и собирал Animation Controller с **Generic** Rig вместо **Humanoid** в настройках после испорта в Unity где вкладки (Materials,Anim,Rig), а Root Motion это движение анимациями, тут моя вторая проблема я двигал анимацию кодом.

В общем каждая **анимация** должна быть с **Humanoid** Rig перед использованием, и двигайте персонажом или в моем случае AI с помощью анимации